# HttpRequestException StatusCode in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, .net-5

The [`StatusCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestexception.statuscode?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpRequestException_StatusCode) property has been added to `HttpRequestException` in .NET 5. Is there any way to use this in Xamarin today?

Answer (score 0):

[The following example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=net-5.0#examples) compares the status returned by an HttpWebResponse with a member of the HttpStatusCode class to determine the status of a response.

```
HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
httpReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

HttpWebResponse httpRes = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();

if (httpRes.StatusCode==HttpStatusCode.Moved)
{
    // Code for moved resources goes here.
}

// Close the response.
httpRes.Close();
```